# ASP.NET MasterPage ContentPlaceHolders not working with external libraries

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

This is a legacy asp.net page using a masterPage with this kind of format:

```
<html>
<head />
<body>
...
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="scriptPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

And in my asp.net aspx page this code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/masterpage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="page.aspx.vb" Inherits="Page"  />
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="scriptPlaceHolder" runat="server">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
 moment();
})
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

The above page throws this error:

```
VM6766:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

In the other hand if I reference the momentjs library in my masterpage it works perfectly,
like this:

```
<html>
<head />
<body>
...

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="scriptPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

Somebody know why ?

Comment: `document.addEventListener()` is not within a separate `<script>` element?

Comment: Thanks @devio yes i missed in this example, but that is not the cause the problem. Do why this could be happening ?

Comment: I suggest you compare the HTML generated by those 2 variants. Maybe there is an obvious difference in generated code that causes the difference in behavior.